# How to draw a line that follows my finger

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to draw a line in Android but I'm having problems with the `onTouch` event of the `FingerLine` class and the `onTouchListener` of the `GameActivity` class. For some reason the `onTouch` event in `FingerLine` works and stops the `GameActivity Touchlisteners` . When I remove the `FingerLine` view from my XML, the `GameActivity Touchlisteners` then work. How can I get the two to work please.

**Fingerline.Java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class FingerLine extends View {
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private float endX;
    private float endY;

    private float newstartX;
    private float newstartY;
    private float newendX;
    private float newendY;
    GameActivity gactivity=new GameActivity();

    public FingerLine(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FingerLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    }


    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(newstartX, newstartY, newendX, newendY, mPaint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                // Set the end to prevent initial jump (like on the demo recording)
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**GameActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ConstraintLayout Letter_panel;
    FingerLine fline;
    TextView letter_button_one;
    TextView letter_button_two;
    TextView letter_button_three;
    TextView letter_button_four;
    TextView letter_button_five;

    Boolean one_isTouched=false;
    Boolean two_isTouched=false;
    Boolean three_isTouched=false;
    Boolean four_isTouched=false;
    Boolean five_isTouched=false;

    TextView textpad;
    String textpadtext="";

    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private float endX;
    private float endY;
    ArrayList myTextviews;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        // how activity in full screen
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //show the activity in full screen

        Letter_panel=this.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout4);
        letter_button_one=this.findViewById(R.id.text_one);//for top A
        letter_button_two=this.findViewById(R.id.text_two);//for top M
        letter_button_three=this.findViewById(R.id.text_three);//for top A
        letter_button_four=this.findViewById(R.id.text_four);//for top E
        letter_button_five=this.findViewById(R.id.text_five);//for top Z
        textpad=this.findViewById(R.id.textpad);
        textpad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        letter_button_Method();

    }

    private void letter_button_Method() {
        Letter_panel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Log.d("tag","in onTouch...");
                checkTouch(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    public void checkTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if((letter_button_one.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_one.getRight())) { if((letter_button_one.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_one.getBottom())&& one_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter A 1
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_one.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            one_isTouched=true;// used to know if first button was touched
        }
        }else

        if((letter_button_two.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_two.getRight())) { if((letter_button_two.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_two.getBottom())&& two_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter M 2
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_two.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            two_isTouched=true;
        }
        }else
        if((letter_button_three.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_three.getRight())) { if((letter_button_three.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_three.getBottom())&& three_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter A 3
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_three.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            three_isTouched=true;
        }
        }else
        if((letter_button_four.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_four.getRight())) { if((letter_button_four.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_four.getBottom())&& four_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter E 4
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_four.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            four_isTouched=true;
        }
        }else
        if((letter_button_five.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_five.getRight())) { if((letter_button_five.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_five.getBottom())&& five_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter Z 5
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_five.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            five_isTouched=true;
        }
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                all_letters_buttonFalse();//turns all letter pressed state back to false
                textpadtext="";
                textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
                textpad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
    public void all_letters_buttonFalse(){
        one_isTouched=false;
        two_isTouched=false;
        three_isTouched=false;
        four_isTouched=false;
        five_isTouched=false;
    }
}
```

Then this is how I add and display the fingerline view via XML.

**activity_game.xml**

````
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:background="@drawable/letters_panel"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.70"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.211"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.368"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.65">

            <store.imastudio.wordmaster.FingerLine
                android:id="@+id/draw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            </com.homestudio.wmaster.FingerLine> ```
````

Comment: When I did that the Action_Move stops working and the line is never drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Fingerline View` from `activity_game.xml` and use the following code
**GameActivity**

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ConstraintLayout Letter_panel;
    FingerLine fline;
    TextView letter_button_one;
    TextView letter_button_two;
    TextView letter_button_three;
    TextView letter_button_four;
    TextView letter_button_five;

    Boolean one_isTouched=false;
    Boolean two_isTouched=false;
    Boolean three_isTouched=false;
    Boolean four_isTouched=false;
    Boolean five_isTouched=false;

    TextView textpad;
    String textpadtext="";

    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private float endX;
    private float endY;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        // how activity in full screen
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //show the activity in full screen

        Letter_panel=this.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout4);
        letter_button_one=this.findViewById(R.id.text_one);//for top A
        letter_button_two=this.findViewById(R.id.text_two);//for top M
        letter_button_three=this.findViewById(R.id.text_three);//for top A
        letter_button_four=this.findViewById(R.id.text_four);//for top E
        letter_button_five=this.findViewById(R.id.text_five);//for top Z
        textpad=this.findViewById(R.id.textpad);
        textpad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        FingerLine fingerLine=new FingerLine(this);//For line
        FingerLine.addView(fingerline);// For line
        letter_button_Method();

    }

    private void letter_button_Method() {
        Letter_panel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Log.d("tag","in onTouch...");
                checkTouch(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    public void checkTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if((letter_button_one.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_one.getRight())) { if((letter_button_one.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_one.getBottom())&& one_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter A 1
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_one.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            one_isTouched=true;// used to know if first button was touched
        }
        }else

        if((letter_button_two.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_two.getRight())) { if((letter_button_two.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_two.getBottom())&& two_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter M 2
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_two.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            two_isTouched=true;
        }
        }else
        if((letter_button_three.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_three.getRight())) { if((letter_button_three.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_three.getBottom())&& three_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter A 3
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_three.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            three_isTouched=true;
        }
        }else
        if((letter_button_four.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_four.getRight())) { if((letter_button_four.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_four.getBottom())&& four_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter E 4
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_four.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            four_isTouched=true;
        }
        }else
        if((letter_button_five.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= letter_button_five.getRight())) { if((letter_button_five.getTop() <= y) && (y <= letter_button_five.getBottom())&& five_isTouched==false) {

            //For Letter Z 5
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
            textpad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textpadtext=textpadtext+letter_button_five.getText();
            textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
            five_isTouched=true;
        }
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                // Set the end to prevent initial jump (like on the demo recording)
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                all_letters_buttonFalse();//turns all letter pressed state back to false
                textpadtext="";
                textpad.setText(""+textpadtext);
                textpad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //code below is for drawing line
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
    public void all_letters_buttonFalse(){
        one_isTouched=false;
        two_isTouched=false;
        three_isTouched=false;
        four_isTouched=false;
        five_isTouched=false;
    }
    public class FingerLine extends View {
        private final Paint mPaint;

        public FingerLine(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public FingerLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        }
        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```